# How do you replace the richTextBox scrollbar?

Tags: c#

I'm using a theme ([ModernUI](https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui), C#) made by viperneo and some other guys and in that theme there's a scrollbar component.

I want to replace the default scrollbar used by the default richTextBox component with the scrollbar from the theme. Is that possible? And if so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these three links can help you through:

[Custom Scrollbar Library version 1.1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1084/Custom-Scrollbar-Library-version)

[How to skin scrollbars for Panels, in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C)

[HOWTO: Theme scrollbars of controls on a Windows Forms modal window from a Visual Studio 2012 add-in.](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012026.aspx)

Comment: I don't know how these links are going to help me. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: For example: Use the second link to create your own custom `ScrollBar` and then assign it to your `RichTextBox`

Comment: But I don't need to create my own scrollbar, I need to replace the scrollbar with the scrollbar from the theme I'm using.

Comment: Create a panel and add a custom scrollbar to it